# T-SQL Options ( Microsoft SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Why can't I use the `RECOMPILE` option along with `FOR REPLICATION` when creating stored procedures?

Comment: Probably should rephrase: Why did MS design Sql Server such that...

Answer (score 1):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa225939%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) explicitly states

> #### FOR REPLICATION
>
> Specifies that stored procedures
>   created for replication cannot be
>   executed on the Subscriber. A stored
>   procedure created with the FOR
>   REPLICATION option is used as a stored
>   procedure filter and only executed
>   during replication. **This option cannot
>   be used with the WITH RECOMPILE
>   option.**

Why they choose not to allow this is beyond me.